# Return two li objects under the same container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So iam having and it works just fine. But

```
<ul className="users">
  {users.slice(sliceTopNum, users.length).map(user => {
    i++;
    if (i && i % 5 === 0) {
      return (
        <li>
          <div>
            <p>I am an Ad</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <li>
          <div>
            <p>I am {coupon.name}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    }
  })}
</ul>
```

But i want the else to return 2 li items at the same time. How can i do that? It seems JSX doesnt let you do that. But i am sure there might be a way to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

```
<li><div><p>I am {coupon.name}</p></div></li>    
<li><div><p>I am an Ad</p></div></li>
```

Comment: it depends on your version of React. You can either wrap the return in a div with two li children, or a React.Fragment with the latest version

Comment: in react 15 you have to put them into a container e.g. <div></div>  you can use fragments in react 16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of React (16) You can use Fragments to return multiple elements without having to use wrapper element like a `div`:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <li><div><p>I am {coupon.name}</p></div></li>    
  <li><div><p>I am an Ad</p></div></li>
</React.Fragment>
```